# Highstock tooltip formatter if using split : true

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can i edit tooltip value when i use split:true for my tooltip
I made an example of what I will have if I use default tooltip.formatter

```
split: true,
formatter: function () {
    return 'The value for <b>' + this.x + '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ervo9ab/1/

I just get a first letter of series name, but i wanna see points data

Comment: What is you expected result

Comment: I wanna see real data on tooltips

Comment: check this works without using split http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/5ervo9ab/2/

Comment: I know that it works without split, but i need split

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate over the points array that the `formatter` function returns.

<del>I forked your fiddle to make it work : http://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/5ervo9ab/3/</del>

<del>You can now access the column name and each series `x` and `y` values.</del>

**EDIT:**

<del>Here's a version without jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/5ervo9ab/4/</del>

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the final working version of your initial fiddle without jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/5ervo9ab/5/

How it works:

When `split` is enabled in `tooltip`, you can format it but it takes an array like `['Column name / label', 'Point 1', 'Point 2', 'Point n+1', ...]`.

You can set some HTML inside the array to format your different tooltips content (as I done with `<b>...</b>`).

Then the formatter has to return the final array that contains the formatted content to each tooltip.

```
formatter: function() {
  var s = [];
  s.push(this.x);
  this.points.forEach(function(point) {
    s.push('<b>' + point.series.name + '</b>: ' + point.y);
  });

  return s;
},
split: true
```

Comment: You used shared, but i need split option without shared. Split shows tooltips for each point not in one tooltip, but nearby each point

Comment: Same result on this link =(

Comment: @Annihilus take a look at **EDIT 2** ;)

Comment: Thanks! It Works!